# Deleting file in a list via powershell

Tags: powershell, filepath, delete-file

Based on problem on stackoverflow I tried to run this script to deleting item from filelist.txt recursively via powershell, the script:

```
$TargetFolder = “C:\folder”
$fileList = "C:\folder\filelist.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Path "$targetFolder\*" -Recurse -Include @(Get-Content $fileList) | Remove-Item -Verbose
```

and the problem is, this script wont run when i specified the path of file in the file list, for example:

```
folder/folder/filea
folder/folder/fileb
folder/folder/filec
```

but it will run if I just list the file name like

```
filea
fileb
filec
```

but this is bad because there is same file name in different folder, and I want delete the specific file on specific folder..
please help, and thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fully qualified file names in your file you don't need to bother with the Get-ChildItem.

Use this instead:

```
$fileList = Get-Content "C:\folder\filelist.txt"
ForEach ($File in FileList) {Remove-Item $File -Verbose}
```

In my testing with this file:

```
G:\BEKDocs\Transfer\Calendar2.ics
G:\BEKDocs\Transfer\SyncEventsToCalendar.ics
```

I got this result:

```
PS> $fileList = Get-Content "G:\BEKDocs\Transfer\filelist.txt"
ForEach ($File in $FileList) {Remove-Item $File -Verbose}
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "G:\BEKDocs\Transfer\C
alendar2.ics".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "G:\BEKDocs\Transfer\S
yncEventsToCalendar.ics".

PS>
```